# prevent front end theme from injecting css into wp-admin

Tags: admin-css

I've created a custom child theme of parent theme Cordillera.

This is my child theme's header.php (`<head>`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <?php wp_head();?>
<?php
global $enable_home_page;
$banner = "";
$home_banner_type = cordillera_options_array("home_banner_type",1);
$enable_home_page = cordillera_options_array("enable_home_page");
 if( is_front_page() ){
      $class      = "homepage";
      $banner     = cordillera_get_banner($home_banner_type);
     } 
     else
     {
      $class      = "sitepage";
     }

?>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Waiting+for+the+Sunrise' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<?php if(!(is_front_page())) { ?>
<!-- non-front-page CSS -->
<style>
    html {
      background-color: transparent;
      background: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/bg-product.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
      background-size: cover;
    }
<!-- END non-front-page CSS -->
</style>
<?php } ?>
<?php if(is_page(6)) { ?>
<!-- shop page CSS -->
<style>
    .blog-main {
      background-color: transparent !important;
    }
</style>
<!-- shop page CSS -->
<?php } ?>
</head>
```

I haven't included a link to my child theme's `style.css` in this file, instead using:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_register_style( 'childstyle', get_stylesheet_uri());
    wp_enqueue_style( 'childstyle', get_stylesheet_uri());
});
```

in my child theme's `functions.php`.

However, when logged into Wordpress admin, and viewing WooCommerce pages, some of the admin tool bar links are being colored by my child theme's `style.css`.

[image]

How can I prevent this? Thanks.

Comment: Just to make sure: The style does not interfere with the actual wordpress backend (everything behind wp-admin), but rather with the admin toolbar in the frontend?

Comment: It is very likely (although an assumption) that you have a CSS style for your anchor tags that also include the `!important` declaration, such as `a { color: #0066FF !important }` — so please check your theme parent stylesheet and child theme stylesheet for any similar styles.

Comment: In Firefox, right click on the "Temper Temper..." link and select "Inspect Element (Q)". Go to the right-hand panes at the bottom and select "Computed". Scroll down to find "color". Click the expand triangle and you'll see the list of rules (& their stylesheets) that led to this situation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure your CSS files and remove `!important` rules from your `.css` files and use proper markup (classes, IDs and etc.).

e.g.

```
a, .entry-summary a, .entry-content a {
  color: #06F !important;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

Judging from the test WS which was found with site: search in Google using the URL in your Facebook profile (Temper Temper).

**Edit 1**: Although `!important` rules can be handy from time to time, usually they broke the structure especially if they are not used with proper and detailed planning.

Answer (score -1):

What I'd try to do is applying `!important` to wp-admin native styles. But that would be costly because I would need full control of core files, and I would lose all the styles when upgrading to newer version of wordpress.

If I don't want to mess with native wordpress code and do it specifically with the theme, I'd try to have unique classes for the links and all the theme's conflicting elements with admin area. Like, if I wrap my whole theme in  `<div id="viewport">` and then in my theme file I do #viewport `a{color: yellow !important;}` I guess it would work.

That's all I can think of, may be there would be better way just to prioritize execution of the CSS files by using a custom filter.